# How to create pytest tmp_path with module or function scope?

Tags: python, scope, pytest

I am trying to create a tmp_path using pytest.

This documentation explains how to do it

https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/tmpdir.html

But the scope for the tmp_path is session.

I need to change the session.

Any idea how to create temp directory with pytest with a scope other than session?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: The code is complex to share. Suppose I want to create a temp_dir in each test module and create some subdirectories

Comment: Okay? `tmp_path` having  a session scope does not prevent you from doing that. Not clear on exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to change that session to module. Delete the tmpdir after each module is finished

Answer (score 1):

You can create a fixture with scope "module" or "function" using [tmp_path_factory](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/tmpdir.html#the-tmp-path-factory-fixture) fixture. As follows:

```
import pathlib
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def modular_tmp_path(tmp_path_factory: pytest.TempdirFactory) -> pathlib.Path:
    return tmp_path_factory.mktemp("temp")
```

Comment: The typehint for tmp_path_factory should be `pytest.TempPathFactory` instead.

Comment: If this results in directory collisions between tests, adding the `numbered=True` argument to `.mktemp()` may help.

Answer (score 0):

One way is use a module scoped fixture to delete all created directories during the teardown.

```
import pytest  
import shutil  

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="module")
def delete_temp_dir(tmp_path):
    yield
    for dir in tmp_path.iterdir():
        shutil.rmtree(dir)
```